# Auth on site with SSL, cookie, headers - don't work

Tags: ruby, authentication, ssl, post, cookies

For authorization on the site https://app.guardsaas.com me need:

1. Open https://app.guardsaas.com/login and get the value "_csrf_token"
2. Make a POST request https://app.guardsaas.com/login_check
   with parameters:

   '_username' = login
   '_password' = pass
   '_remember_me' = 'on'
   '_csfr_token' = token from p.1

I wrote a script that first gets a token, and then it is authorized with the help of the site, but it does not work, the error can be covered in SSL, cookie, tried out a bunch of different options - nothing comes out

My code:

```
require "net/http"
require 'net/https'
require "uri"

uri = URI('https://app.guardsaas.com/login')
token = ""
text = ""

http = Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port,
  :use_ssl => uri.scheme == 'https', 
  :verify_mode => OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE)

# make a request to get the server's cookies
response = http.get('https://app.guardsaas.com/login')
puts response.code
if (response.code == '200')
    all_cookies = response.get_fields('set-cookie')
    cookies_array = Array.new
    all_cookies.each { | cookie |
        cookies_array.push(cookie.split('; ')[0])
    }
    cookies = cookies_array.join('; ')

    text = response.body.to_s
    st = text.index('_csrf_token" value=').to_i
    token = text[st+20..st+19+40]
    puts "token: " + token

    data = {
    "_username" => 'login',
    "_password" => 'pass',
    "_remember_me" => 'on',
    "_csrf_token"  => token
    }

    data = URI.encode_www_form(data)

    headers = {
    'Cookie' => cookies,
    'Referer' => 'https://app.guardsaas.com',
    'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }

    headers = URI.encode_www_form(headers)

    data = http.post('https://app.guardsaas.com/login_check', data, headers)


    puts data.body
end
```

Comment: What the's error - that the password is not accepted, or a bad request e.g. because of CSRF, or something else? Have you monitored a successful login in your browser developer tools - does that match what the browser is posting? But ultimately if the problem is that this isn't behaving exactly as your browser behaves you probably just need to inspect both versions and see where they differ.

Comment: in console browser - all correct, all work! In my script - error auth. I think problem with cookie and PHP_SESSION_ID. In my script its incorrect.